# PhpStorm 10.0, LAMP, 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpstorm

I have already installed a LAMP server on my Ubuntu 12.04.
The server works fine when I place files under the root directory "/var/wwww".
For example a database connection in a file with

```
 $connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

works fine.

The problem appears when I try to create a local server configuration in PhpStorm.
I followed this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html

When I create a normal PHP file in my PhpStorm project and I run it, it works fine. But if I try to create a PHP file with a database connection in the PhpStorm project, the following error appears in the web browser when I run it:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/user/SimpleWebPage/functions.php on line 8
```

That line is the named before:

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

So, I think the problem is that PhpStorm can not find the class 'mysqli', but the LAMP server works fine, because I can work with the work page when the code is placed under "/var/www"

Any idea?

Comment: Are you pointing it to a `php.exe` file? E.g. (using my setup) C:/wamp/bin/phpX.X.X/php.exe where X.X.X is your version number.
Also, is your PHP version up to the latest release (I am using 5.5.12, this has mysqli and works fine)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04, so no php. exe :)
Also, I am working with PHP 5.6.15, it has mysqli and works fine when I am not using PhpStorm, the problem is just with PhpStorm.

Comment: @overflow13 1) Make sure that you have pointed to correct `php` when you configure `PHP Interpreters` in PhpStorm. 2) Please provide `phpinfo()` output captured when executed via PhpStorm.

Comment: @overflow13, just one question from your comment - *How do you run your PHP scripts without a `php.exe` pointer*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using different versions of PHP or different php.ini configuration files (more likely). Probably you have mysqli enabled for the web, but not for your cli. Call the phpinfo() function in both LAMP and from PHPStorm and see if they use the same ini file. If not you'll need to move the configuration settings to the cli php.ini file.

Comment: That was the problem!!!
I were using 2 different versions of PHP, I just had to point the right one and all is working fine right now :)
Than you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I were using 2 different versions of PHP, I just had to point the right one and all is working fine right now :)